# How to use an objects' property as the key for @CachePut?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache, spelevaluationexception

```
public interface MyRespository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @CachePut(value = "mycache", key = "id")
    @Override
    public <S extends MyEntity> S save(S entity);
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Result:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of
>   type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject'
>   - maybe not public?

Comment: Try `#entity.id`..

Comment: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null`

Comment: Apparently you're persisting a null entity

Comment: No I'm not. It's jujst that the `#entity.id` cannot be resolved somehow. The case works fine when I remove the `@CachePut` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the object by index with `key = "#a0.id"` worked, but I still don't know why it's not possible to access the object by its name.

Comment: You can use #id instead